# reflections in java

Tags: java

Hi
Can anybody explain me reflection API in java with example.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Comment: To make this a "real question" - add a question mark... :/

Answer (score 2):

First google link:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Second google link:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html